# Connecting to different servers based on a parameter in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a basic python script which loads data from SQL server to oracle.

The data is coming from 2 different SQL Servers, but the table structure is same.

Is it possible, to connect to these servers based on the parameter that we can pass using command line?

For Example, Let's say the data from company1 is coming from SQL Server1 and for comapany2 from SQL Server2. When i pass the parameter as Company1, it should connect to SQL Server1 and load the data into table1 and similarly for company2.

Sample Table:

```
 ID        Balance    Company
------------------------------
2449079    2282.64    @Param
2449079    0.00       @Param
```

I want the parameter value(which is passed by command line) to be in the Company column.

Comment: you may want to show us how are you connecting right now. Then someone may be able to suggest  how to configure it via a command line param.

Comment: I am using putty (UNIX) to connect. i am using the argv function to pass in the command line parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using `sys.argv` to pass the parameters